# Send database to Dropbox - com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$IllegalArgument: Illegal datastore ID

Tags: android, dropbox

I'm developing an app to build lists of different names. The content of a list is in a table contained inside of a database. What I wish is to send some of these tables toward Dropbox datastore in order to share them between several devices.

For my practice, I start by trying to create a simple table on Dropbox after having connected my app with it. But I have an error message and I cannot figure out why...

Here my activity:

```
public class ListingArticlesDropb extends Activity implements PersonneAdapterListener{


    static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;  // This value is up to you

    private Button mLinkButton;
    private Button mUnlinkButton;

    private DbxAccountManager mAccountManager;
    private DbxDatastoreManager mDatastoreManager;
    private DbxAccount account ;

    final private String APP_KEY = **** APP_KEY **** ;
    final private String APP_SECRET = **** APP_SECRET **** ;
    DbxDatastore datastore;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_articles);


        /**
         * Get objects from the precedent activity
         */
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String extras = bundle.getString("Title");

        /**
         * Connection to the datastore Dropbox
         */
        // Set up the account manager
        mAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);   
        mAccountManager.startLink((Activity)ListingArticlesDropb.this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);


        // Set up the datastore manager
        if (mAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
            try {
                // Use Dropbox datastores
                mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.forAccount(mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Dropbox", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (DbxException.Unauthorized e) {
                System.out.println("Account was unlinked remotely");
            }
        }
        if (mDatastoreManager == null) {
            // Account isn't linked yet, use local datastores
            mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.localManager(mAccountManager);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Locale", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                account = mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount();
                Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    // Migrate any local datastores to the linked account
                    mDatastoreManager.migrateToAccount(account);
                    // Now use Dropbox datastores
                    mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.forAccount(account);

                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Link failed or was cancelled by the user
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


        // ---------- The problem comes here ------------- //
        try {
       //  This line makes my app to stop.
            DbxDatastore datastore = mDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore("Articles");
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }





    @Override
    public void onClickNom(Article item, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onClickNomToDelete(Article item, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Here the error message :

```
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.dvp_list7/com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb}: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$IllegalArgument: Illegal datastore ID 'Articles'.
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3337)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3380)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:155)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5096)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961): Caused by: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$IllegalArgument: Illegal datastore ID 'Articles'.
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxDatastore.checkId(DbxDatastore.java:534)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore(DbxDatastoreManager.java:342)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb.onActivityResult(ListingArticlesDropb.java:113)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5342)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3333)
10-21 19:39:02.410: E/AndroidRuntime(22961):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks a lot for people who will help me!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is accurate. You used "Articles" as a datastore ID, but datastore IDs for private datastores must be "1-64 characters containing only lowercase letters, digits, dot, hyphen or underscore, and they must not begin or end with dot." (See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/http#general.)

The issue here is the capital "A".

Comment: Thank you for your good notice @smarx! However, even after remplacing "Articles" by "articles" no datastore are created and I get a new error message. It would seem having a problem of cache. I'm going to edit my Question to update it with this error message.

Comment: Please just ask a new question, since your new question is unrelated to this one.